# How to check is value in form was changed from initial

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms

I have reactive form in my Angular 7 app:

```
  this.userInfoForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      displayName: [this.user.displayName, [
        Validators.required,
      ]],
    })
```

How to check, is initial value in input was changed? Because when I use `userInfoForm.dirty` it return true, even if I remove 1 symbol from value and then add it back.

Comment: Have posted the answer pls check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do like this, will use `valueChanges()` method of FormControl which *returns an Observable that emits the latest values. You can, therefore, subscribe to `valueChanges` to update instance variables or perform operations.*

```
intialValue: any; // Define one property to store the initial value of the control

this.intialValue = this.userInfoForm.get('displayName').value; // Store initial value

// and then subscribe to valueChanges method of FormControl to get the latest value
this.userInfoForm.get('displayName').valueChanges.subscribe(value => {
  console.log('Intital Value', this.intialValue)
  console.log('New Value', value);
})
```

[`Working Demo`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tesj8a)

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this would be to get the value of the form, `form.value` after it has been created, and save it using something like - `this.initialFormValue = JSON.stringify(this.form.value)`

Whenever you want to check if the form was changed e.g. on submit, get the current value, `JSON.stringify(this.form.value)` and compare to `this.initialFormValue`

You can't reliably test by comparing the original model and the form.value, as in many cases numbers on the model will be returned as strings, and the ordering of the forms underlying object might differ from the model

I haven't tested this, but in theory it should work!!